# php json_decode side by side with a variable

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation

I have two questions:

1. I read code that was written by a former programmer. I cannot contact this programmer because I am not in contact with him!

   ```php
   public function getValidatorString(string $paramName)
   {
       // add error management
       return json_decode($this->Parametres, true)[$paramName]['validator'];
   }
   ```

   My question is: How can I put side by side `json_decode and an array like` [$paramName]['validator'];` I never saw this type of code. It works! What is the purpose?

   `json_decode($this->Parametres, true)` return a big array of parameters. The line search in this array if
   `[$paramName]['validator']` exist. If yes, return the string `"required"`.
2. ```php
   $validatorArray = [];
   foreach ($params as $paramName => $paramValue) {
       if (array_key_exists($paramName, json_decode($report->Parametres)))
           $validatorArray[$paramName] = $report->getValidatorString($paramName);
   }
   // On valide les données saisies
   $request->validate($validatorArray);
   ```

   The sentence `$request->validate($validatorArray);` There are no rules in the code, class, or controller for this validate function. It works!

   Question: Where does `$request` get the rules to validate `$validatorArray`? How can `$request->validate()` work without predefined rules?

I hope my questions are clear.

Thank you.

Comment: "How can we put side by side json_decode and an array like [$paramName]['validator']; I never seen this kind of code." — You've never seen something like `[$paramName]` next to an array? (You did say that it gives you an array in your next sentence).

Comment: "Where $request found the rules for validate" — How should we know? You haven't told us what `$request` is or provided a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like its time to hire a replacement programmer.

Comment: If you really want to read and understand this code I suggest you first follow some PHP and Laravel tutorials to familiarise yourself with the basics. Things will start falling into place after that

Answer (score 1):

The rules seem to be defined in the class's `Parametres` property. Based on the code you provided, I believe it's just a convoluted way to declare optional validation rules.

`$this->Parametres` probably looks like this:

```json
{"name":{"validator":"required|string"},"age":{"validator":"required|numeric"},"some_required_param":{"validator":"required"}}

/* expanded
{
  "name": {
    "validator": "required|string"
  },
  "age": {
    "validator": "required|numeric"
  },
  "some_required_param": {
    "validator": "required"
  }
}
*/
```

`json_encode($this->Parametres, true)` would then be this array:

```php
[
    'name' => [
        'validator' => 'required|string',
    ],
    'age' => [
        'validator' => 'required|numeric',
    ],
    'some_required_param' => [
        'validator' => 'required',
    ],
]
```

- `getValidatorString('name')` returns `'required|string'`
- `getValidatorString('age')` returns `'required|numeric'`
- `getValidatorString('some_required_param')` returns `'required'`.

Maybe Parametres is sent to the server via an ajax or fetch request.

---

Assume the `$request` has only `name` and `age`, but not `some_required_param`.

```
// this would fail since some_required_param is not present. 
$request->validate([
  "name" => "required|string",
  "age" => "required|numeric",
  "some_required_param" => "required"
]);
```

---

I'm also assuming `$params` is the parameters of the request. What you'd get by doing `$request->all()`. In my example, it would return an array like this:

`['name' => 'something', 'age' => 28]`.

```php
$validation_rules = [];
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
    // if there is a validation rule defined in Parametres for $key    
    if (array_key_exists($key, json_decode($report->Parametres))) {
        // add this rule to $validation_rules array
        $validation_rules[$key] = $report->getValidatorString($paramName);
    }
}
// validate request based on rules we just added.
$request->validate($validation_rules);
```

This would be equivalent to just doing

```php
$request->validate([
  "name" => "required|string",
  "age" => "required|numeric",
]);
```